# Spring + Hessian on Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, hessian

I have a task to write a web service with use of Hessian and Spring.
Unfortunately there is not enough information so i can't make it work myself...

Please can anyone write a simple Hello World for me? 
My version always shows 404 when accesing with browser... I'm new to java so if smb knows how to help tell me what files of my project to share.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you use Hessian, why not start with Resin as servlet container?

Comment: I dont'know.. Is it better? I'm new to java world... so i have a lot to know)

Comment: Hessian is a binary protocol, a web browser is not appropriate - what sort of Hello World are you looking for?

Comment: Any minimal just to be sure that it works. As i know Hessian works on top of HTTP so if browser show me binary abracadabra it would be enough